# I am not understanding why the css file "signin.css" is not been found by my flask app.error -"GET /signin.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -

Tags: python, html, css, flask

(Python file)
This is the python Flask file
I dont think there is any problem in this

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_mail import Mail
import json
from datetime import datetime


with open('config1.json', 'r') as c:
    params = json.load(c)["params"]

local_server = True
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.update(
    MAIL_SERVER = 'smtp.gmail.com',
    MAIL_PORT = '465',
    MAIL_USE_SSL = True,
    MAIL_USERNAME = params['gmail-user'],
    MAIL_PASSWORD=  params['gmail-password']
)
mail = Mail(app)
if(local_server):
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = params['local_uri']
else:
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = params['prod_uri']

db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class Contacts(db.Model):
    sno = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)
    phone_num = db.Column(db.String(12), nullable=False)
    msg = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=False)
    date = db.Column(db.String(12), nullable=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)


class Posts(db.Model):
    sno = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)
    slug = db.Column(db.String(21), nullable=False)
    content = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=False)
    tagline = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=False)
    date = db.Column(db.String(12), nullable=True)
    img_file = db.Column(db.String(12), nullable=True)


@app.route("/")
def home():
    posts = Posts.query.filter_by().all()[0:params['no_of_posts']]
    return render_template('index.html', params=params, posts=posts)


@app.route("/post/<string:post_slug>", methods=['GET'])
def post_route(post_slug):
    post = Posts.query.filter_by(slug=post_slug).first()
    return render_template('post.html', params=params, post=post)

@app.route("/about")
def about():
    return render_template('about.html', params=params)



                                 #this is the root for login.html(end point)
@app.route("/dashboard",methods=['GET','POST'])
def dashboard():
    return render_template('login.html', params=params)



@app.route("/contact", methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def contact():
    if(request.method=='POST'):
        name = request.form.get('name')
        email = request.form.get('email')
        phone = request.form.get('phone')
        message = request.form.get('message')
        entry = Contacts(name=name, phone_num = phone, msg = message, date= datetime.now(),email = email )
        db.session.add(entry)
        db.session.commit()
        mail.send_message('New message from ' + name,
                          sender=email,
                          recipients = [params['gmail-user']],
                          body = message + "\n" + phone
                          )
    return render_template('contact.html', params=params)


app.run(debug=True)
```

HTML file
(login.html)
This is the main problem i think so
Actually i am learning wed dev from codewithharry youtube channel
flask tutorial #14
I think there is a minor mistake which i am not getting
may be your experience can find it out

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../../../favicon.ico">

    <title>Signin Template for Bootstrap</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">


    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="signin.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body class="text-center">

 <link href="{{ url_for ('static', filename='css/signin.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
 
    <form class="form-signin" action="/dashboard" method="post">
      {% set fname = 'img/'+  params['login_image']  %}
      <img class="mb-4" src="{{url_for('static', filename=fname)}}" alt="" width="72" height="72">
      <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Admin Login</h1>
      <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
      <input type="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>
      <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
      <input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
      <div class="checkbox mb-3">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
        </label>
      </div>
      <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
      <p class="mt-5 mb-3 text-muted">© {{params['blog_name'] }} 2017-2018</p>
    </form>


 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are loading the CSS file twice. Once just below the `<body...>` tag, and once a couple of lines above.

There are two issues:

Firstly, the CSS file should be loaded only once and inside the `<head>` tag. So the first `<link...>` tag is in the proper location. But,...

... secondly, in the first `<link...>` tag, you are not using the `{{ url_for(...) }}` syntax for static files. **This is necessary**.

In other words:

- Make use of the `{{ url_for(...) }}` function on your first line using `signin.css`
- Remove the second line using `signin.css`.

---

When you leave out the `{{ url_for(...) }}` function for static files, the browser will try to access a URL path `/signin.css`. That path will then go into `flask` and it will try to find a matching URL "route". For static files like JS or CSS you don't add `@route(...)` decorators, but rather put them into the `static` folder. And you need to let flask determine the proper URL for static files using the `{{ url_for('static', filename) }}` pattern.

Comment: I appreciate your efforts but it is still showing error when I am inspecting it in chrome.      Error is:  failed to load resource: sign.css:1 404 error

Comment: I am learning this from codewithharry YouTube channel. His program works fine but not mine.dont know why

Comment: Have you verified if the file "signin.css" is saved inside the `static/css` folder? If you are on Linux, can you can you run the following command and add the output to the question: `tree`. If that is not available, an equivalent command is `find . | sort`.

Comment: Actually i am using bootstrap tamplet singin.css.first I save the file by using save as feature on the chrome and saved it in the static folder.I know it is really hard to understand what i am saying so pls if you could search code with harry flask tutorial #14  and see why his flask app runs fine and not mine,i have just pasted his source code  and did the same procedure like him but at the end his code works but not mine. pls help.i will really give you a like if you helped me out of this

Comment: I just had a quick look and his code on the page looks incorrect as well (for the same reasons mentioned in my answer). Can you add a screenshot of both the "network" tab in the debug-tools, and also the console output of Flask when you access the page? It might help debugging, but I am afraid it will only confirm the points I made in my answer.

Comment: Yaa i too think you are right,his code seems to be wrong because I have tried every possible thing to fix it but it's not working,I even tried your advice I thought yes now it's gonna work but then too it doesnt work for me. Now I have decided to change my tutor to "Web dev simplified".it's a bit frustrating for me that I have to start from the beginning.i am thinking to quit flask and go for java script,node js but I love python don't know why . pls do leave  your  views on it,,at the end thanks for your valuable feedback I will never forget you and your efforts for me.Thanks

Comment: Please don't dismiss a language or framework on the basis of a bad tutorial/tutor. I understand it can be frustrating especially in the beginning because there is so much to learn. If you switch now, you will solve one problem but you will get stuck somewhere else. You have not made a wrong choice with Flask (considering how many people successfully use it). You just need to get "over the hump". I would recommend [the official Flask tutorial](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/tutorial/)